# How to pass browserify --require file to angular module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, npm, browserify

I have engineered a build for an Angular SPA using NPM to call the browserify script to bundle it, i.e. you can run from the terminal `npm run build:js` which calls the following script in package.json:

```
"build:js": "browserify -r ./params-dev.js -e src/app/index.js -o build/index.js"
```

What I'm trying to do now is to create two different config objects for prod and QA. Each one will require a different file: `params-dev.js` or `params-prod.js` (like in the command above).

I am wondering how to access these variables in the resulting bundle? They are environment specific and some of it points to analytics codes, etc. Furthermore, I'm trying to move them out of the global scope, where they currently live.

Here is a sample of the params files I'd like to include with the bundles.  There will be one for prod and one for QA:

```
var merge = require('merge'),
    params = require('./params')

exports.config = merge(params, {
    env: 'prod',
    analyticsCode: 'blah08yweblah2e823lnblah',
    otherProps: '...etc...'
})
```

So how do I access these variables now in my AngularJS module? I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Anyone have any ideas? Please let me know if you need more info.

In case it helps, my index.js looks like

```
(function () {
    // common app require statements
    require('blah')
    require('blah-2')
    angular.module('app', [require('angular-route')])
    // etc etc
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. :) If I add the target to the end of the required file path in the command like so:

```
"build:js": "browserify -r ./params-dev.js:params -e src/app/index.js -o build/index.js"
```

I can access the object by adding `var params = require('params')` to my angular file.